# GridView Color From Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an SQL Database which contains hex codes for colors. I want the change every single row of the grid according to the hex code. One single line contains(On DB) Team, Year, City, Stadium, Fore_Color, Back_Color. I tried using `Eval` to get the specified color for each line but couldn't manage to do it. I am using c#, asp.net.

For Example why this does not work?:

```
 e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.BackColor,"Back_Color")));
```

OR THIS:

```
e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("Back_Color").ToString());
    e.Row.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("Front_Color").ToString());
```

This gives the following error: 
Databinding methods such as `Eval()`, `XPath()`, and `Bind()` can only be used in the context of a `databound` control.

I tried saying `OnRowDataBound` for gridview but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `RowDataBound` event of the `GridView` and [`ColorTranslator.FromHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
protected void GrdidView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        Color backColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row.Field<string>("Back_Color"));
        e.Row.BackColor = backColor;
        Color frontColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row.Field<string>("Front_Color"));
        e.Row.ForeColor = frontColor;
    }
}
```

If you are using a different `DataItem` look at it in the debugger and change it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! You literally saved my life!

Comment: @EmirArditi: You're welcome. Remember to accept the answer if your question is answered.